# SSL issue with XMLRPC using Python and Wordpress

Tags: python, wordpress, ssl, xml-rpc

I am attempting to use XMLRPC to post from Python to Wordpress. The website has SSL and I am getting the following error:

```
SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:720)
```

I have spent almost a full day trying to resolve this, but cannot figure it out. Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem.

```
import sys
if sys.version_info >= (2, 7, 9):
    import ssl
    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you very much for providing the solution.